# Pandas dataframe csv with constant spacing?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a pandas dataframe which i regularly export to a csv. I like to scroll over it to see if anything is out of place and i was wondering if there is a way built-in way to get constant spacing in the csv export for better readability?

as in turn this :

```
Bill, 6789, 0.8900987U, Yes, 
Steve, 02, -0.23, No,
```

into

```
Bill , 6789, 0.8900987U, Yes, 
Steve, 02  , -0.23     , No ,
```

or

```
Bill,  6789, 0.8900987U, Yes, 
Steve, 02,   -0.23,      No,
```

Comment: What you should rather be looking for is to install csv reader extension. You can try `Rainbow CSV`

Comment: Thank you, this is a good turnaround and i'll take a look into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
pad = lambda x: x.str.pad(x.str.len().max())

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, dtype=str)
df.apply(pad).to_csv('out.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

`out.csv`:

```
Bill , 6789, 0.8900987U, Yes, 
Steve, 02  , -0.23     , No ,
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm not used to using lambdas. I put your exact code as is and i get an error saying that apply(pad) gets an error as "width must be an integer type, not a float". 
I don't understand why it bugs since you convert the data to string using dtype=str in the read_csv()

Comment: Try: `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, dtype=str).fillna('')` to fill nan values by empty string

Comment: Using a lambda function is like to create a named function: `def pad(x): return x.str.pad(x.str.len().max())`